# Flutter delete Hive Database on Update

Tags: flutter, dart, hivedb, flutter-hive

I have a Flutter app and I am using Hive to store data.

I have deleted some adapters which were used previously. This caused an error and I have to delete the old database.

Now, if I roll out an update, how do I make sure the old Hive database gets deleted when the user updates the app so that it causes no issues.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of deleting, run a database [migration](https://pub.dev/packages/hive/versions/0.1.0#migration).

> ```
> Hive.box("myBox", version: 5, migrator: (oldVersion, newVersion, box) async {
>   await box.delete("unusedKey");
>   await box.put("newKey", 7);
> });
> ```

If you want to delete it anyway,

- Read the app version, [package_info](https://pub.dev/packages/package_info) may come in handy for that.
- Delete the old db if this app version/build is [running for the first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740617/check-if-an-application-is-on-its-first-run-with-flutter) after installing/updating.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `box.clear()` indeed this is an answer you may be expecting my Best Friend.

Answer (score 1):

Hive.deleteFromDisk() can just wipe it clean.