# Flutter Shared Preferences, check if first run not working

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences, flutter-sharedpreference

I was originally following the code for the answer found here:

[Check if an application is on its first run with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44740617/check-if-an-application-is-on-its-first-run-with-flutter)

And I was incorporating it into the [introduction_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen) package on pub.dev

I successfully have it loading the page for my onboarding page on first load. Then when I am done with the onboarding page I try to set the shared preference value to 'true' so when I reload the app it will skip the onboarding page, but it does not work when i test in my emulator in VS Code.

I check the value on first book here:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  _MyAppState() {
    MySharedPreferences.instance
        .getBooleanValue("isfirstRun")
        .then((value) => setState(() {
              isLoggedIn = value;
            }));
  }
```

I load the onboarding screen if false here:

```
    home: isLoggedIn ? MainPage() : OnBoard(),
```

My Shared Pref dart file is:

import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

```
class MySharedPreferences {
  MySharedPreferences._privateConstructor();

  static final MySharedPreferences instance =
      MySharedPreferences._privateConstructor();
  setBooleanValue(String key, bool value) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    myPrefs.setBool(key, value);
  }

  Future<bool> getBooleanValue(String key) async {
    SharedPreferences myPrefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return myPrefs.getBool(key) ?? false;
  }
}
```

When the onboarding is complete I run this:

```
          MySharedPreferences.instance.setBooleanValue("loggedin", true);
          //replace with main page
          Route route = MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MainPage());
          Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
```

If I hot reload in VS everything is ok, but if I restart with the the app it runs the onboarding screen each time.

Comment: Did you put the `MySharedPreferences.instance.getBooleanValue("isfirstRun")` in `_MyAppState` inside `initState` for it to run on the widget startup?

Comment: @WilsonToribio just tried that but it didnt work: https://pastebin.com/GNuaLpCb

Comment: Did you get the fix for this?

Answer (score 0):

You should check and change the isLoggedIn value in initstate function

For example

```
  class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool isLoggedIn = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
  MySharedPreferences.instance
      .getBooleanValue("isfirstRun")
      .then((value) => setState(() {
  isLoggedIn = value;
  }));
  super.initState();

  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Something...
  }
```

Comment: I just tried that and it didn't work either: https://pastebin.com/GNuaLpCb

Answer (score 0):

Use `async` and `await` in a separate function and then use it in `initState`:

```
  void verityFirstRun() async {

    final verification = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

    isLoggedIn = verification.getBool("isfirstRun") ?? false;

  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    verityFirstRun();
    super.initState();
  }
```

Use this way of calling the SharedPreferences instance:

```
final verification = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
```

Comment: tried but didnt work either...

Comment: Updated the code, I used the getInstance method from the global SharedPreferences.

Comment: Wi that I get this error:

The method 'getBooleanValue' isn't defined for the type 'SharedPreferences'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'getBooleanValue'

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my answer, try what I did...

Comment: closer but now it doesnt like the key:

Undefined name 'key'.
Try correcting the name to one that is defined, or defining the name.

Comment: Updated my answer, again...

Comment: No errors now, but still boots back into my onboarding when I restart

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243867/discussion-between-wilson-toribio-and-ten-digit-grid).